# How to do port forwarding from guest to host and vice versa in gem5?

Tags: gem5

For example, I want to be able to do on guest:

```
nc -l -p 45455
```

and then on host:

```
echo asdf | nc  localhost 45455
```

and have the guest receive the `asdf`.

My initial goal with this is to setup `gdbserver`, but this could also be used for fun things like simulating clusters.

For the specific case of `gdbserver`, it is also be possible to step debug userland processes with gem5's default GDB server [as described here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/a1a6a5d6fb417238ce4064ef7b3319686f02fd6b#gem5-gdb-step-debug-userland-process), but that may be more unreliable.

In QEMU for example, I can do that with:

```
-netdev user,hostfwd=tcp::45455-:45455,id=net0
```

I am also interested in the guest to host direction, although that I haven't managed to do in QEMU yet: https://serverfault.com/questions/769874/how-to-forward-a-port-from-guest-to-host-in-qemu-kvm

If it is not possible, I will accept a "it is not possible answer" from a well known dev :-)

https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15207.html

Comment: hi, did you solve that problem ? I need port forwarding for gem5 to listen custom vnc server running on gem5.

Comment: @geekowl nope, never found a solution. The best approach would be to understand exactly how it works on QEMU and then see what gem5 is missing.

Comment: I see... is it possible to stream frames using vncserver (default gem5 ) ? I want to run some gl samples and get frames over vnc port without installing X on gem5 disc ( it's too slow ) . I could do this on qemu but it supports port forward etc.

Comment: @geekowl I did manage to connect with vncserver to gem5 via its magic VNC interface, gem5 shows something like `system.vncserver: Listening for connections on port 5900` at startup. see also: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/gem5-graphic-mode gem5 also dumps the last frame at `m5out/system.framebuffer.png`, but it keeps overwriting that file for every new frame.

Comment: yes i know that but ... i use gem5 to model gpu that has driver side too. so using installed driver i can test my gpu model on gem5 (i was using qemu). we have own vncserver instaelled with gpu driver but because of that port forwarding problem i cant use it. i tested vncserver but it didn't capture any gl tests frames. i used frame-capture too => nothing... well i'm disappointed... thanks for replies.